# Why can't I store a managed variable in an unmanaged class?

Tags: visual-c++

I have user interface setup in visual studio 2005 that has a textbox and a button.  I am trying to store the text in the textbox when the button is pressed using storeText(String^).  My compilation error says "cannot declare a managed variable in an unmanaged class".  Why can't I do this?  What is the proper solution to my problem.  I am using visual c++.

```
#include <string>
using System::String;

class Stuff
{
public:
Stuff()
{
}

void storeText(String^ s)
{
    something = s;
}

String^ getText()
{
    return something;
}

private:
String^ something;
};
```

Comment: hmm, I don't know... Use managed classes ? :)

Comment: Searching Google for that error message finds this discussion which links to two other places, which both seem to have good information and solutions for the issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/963b5d92-e41b-4dea-9344-88860af81f8c

Answer (score 0):

If you're in unmanaged code, then the GC won't know what references you have or haven't got around. You're supposed to convert it to a native std::string and then use that.